# How to change StackExchange email address?

Tags: support, profile-page, openid

I've been searching all over for an answer to this and can find nothing 100% solid.

I have a StackExchange login that has an outdated email address but I can't find any way to change it. I figured, maybe I'd try adding a new login then removing the old one, but I can't just add a new login with an email address, I have to choose Google, or AOL, or some other third party provider and I don't want. I *just* want to change my email address! This is extremely frustrating. Any help would be great.

Comment: But there's a workaround here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704

Comment: Wow, all that, just to change my email address! *sigh* Ok, thanks for the link.

Comment: I'd like to make it less painful, but it's a non-trivial change and other more pressing things keep coming up.

Comment: As a coder, I totally understand. Thanks!